# Invert Y axis in Highcharts

Tags: highcharts

Is there an option to invert the Y-axis in a Highcharts chart? For instance, if the axis would normally run from 0 at the bottom of the axis to 100 at the top, it should instead be shown running from 100 at the bottom to 0 at the top. This is useful, for instance, when using a chart with two Y-axis and you want to see the correlation between two lines with an inverse relationship.

Note that I'm not talking here about the [inverted](http://www.highcharts.com/ref/#chart--inverted) option in Highcharts, which just flips the position of the X and Y axes.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Have you already examined the [reversed](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/yAxis.reversed) option on the y-axis and the [example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/highcharts/yaxis/reversed/) from the api?

From the jsfiddle example because of stackoverflow's rule to include code when linking to jsfiddle:

```
},
yAxis: {
    reversed: true
},
```

This sounds like what you're looking for, but as an aside, you may want to re-consider [dual-scaled axes](http://www.perceptualedge.com/articles/visual_business_intelligence/dual-scaled_axes.pdf).

Comment: Thanks, precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

use   reversed: true,

```
yAxis: {
                reversed: true,
                showFirstLabel: false,
                showLastLabel: true
            },
```